# Error:Could not find fabric.aar (io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17)

Tags: android, gradle, google-fabric

it worked before I don't change anything but today I got this error, here my gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}}
```

Answer (score 17):

Looks like jcenter is reporting that it has fabric and crashlytics but they don't.

What fixed it for me is to move the fabric maven up before jcenter like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

Comment: For someone who don't want to upgrade fabric version, try this solution. Worked on my side.

Answer (score 13):

There is some change in fabric please check this:-
https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-dependency-to-1-4-3

Add this to your gradle:-

```
compile group: 'io.fabric.sdk.android', name: 'fabric', version: '1.4.3'
```

Comment: If you are using crashlytics also update it to `2.9.3` `compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }`

Comment: @Aris_choice where to add this in my gradle ? and which gradle file?

Comment: @Tefa add this to app level build.gradle file . Inside dependencies

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same issue today. I am using crashlytics as well. I have just changed the version of crashlytics to "2.9.3" from "2.6.5" and gradle build successfully.

```
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after reinstalling windows and android studio. I had

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

    }
with

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar')
```

The only solution for me was to upgrade to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

    }

with

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar')
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

1,clean project 
2,changed the version of 
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.2@aar')

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle(Module app): Modify like below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rameshr.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         } 
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    } 

}
```